# SharePoint force unique permissions on site creation

Tags: permissions, site, unique

I am trying to force the 'Use Unique Permissions' when a subsite is created.

My preferred approach is to force the radio button on the `sbnewweb.aspx` page, or to hide that question altogether and set the unique in the `feature receiver`.

Can I manipulate the `sbnewweb.aspx` page contents?

Answer (score 0):

You have two supported options:

1. Add JavaScript through UserCustomAction, which check if it's the sbnewweb.aspx page and if to sets the radio button and hides the section
2. Add css (through AlternateCssUrl) to the site which hides `#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_idPermSection` and have an event receiver to break inheritance (and set AlternateCssUrl)

Finally if you don't care about support (and can do it on all servers) then you could modify `"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\newsbweb.aspx"`, but this isn't supported and might get overriden by service pack.

If you're going with option 1 the following PowerShell can implement that:

```
$gc = Start-SPAssignment
$site = $gc | Get-SPSite http://sp2013-sp
$script = $site.UserCustomActions.Add()
$script.Name = 'DefaultUniquePerm'
$script.Location='ScriptLink'
$script.ScriptBlock='var element = document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_idPermSection_ctl01_RadCreateUniqueSubweb");if(element){element.checked=true;};element = document.getElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_idPermSection");if(element){element.style.display="none";};'
$script.Update()
Stop-SPAssignment $gc
```

Comment: Option 1 sounds like the way I want to go, but I am not sure where to do it.  I want to intercept the 'New Site' click on the "site Contents' page so I can change the radio buttons status and visibility before the user sees the sbnewsite page.

Comment: See edited answer

Answer (score 0):

If you create a subsite with a PowerShell script, you can easily break the permission inheritance:

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb "http://web.whatever.com"
$Web.BreakRoleInheritance($true)
```

It's really that simple!

You would still need to script the SharePoint groups that are included in the site, but the above code breaks the inheritance.